# Prevent an user from accessing other routes - ReactJS - React-Router -

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have two environments: 'Administrador' and 'Alumno'. I would like to know how I can do so such that an 'Administrador' user can not access the routes of an 'Alumno' user and vice versa. I am using React-Router 2.4.0. Is this possible with this technology? I am new to ReactJS (I use version 15.4.2).

Another question: Would it be convenient to update to the new version and transpile all my routes?

Here are my routes:

```
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={NotFound}/>
            <Redirect from="/alumno" to="/alumno/inicio"/>
            <Redirect from="/administrador" to="/administrador/inicio"/>

            <Route path="/" component={App}>

                <Route path="alumno" component={AppAlumno}>
                    <Route path="inicio" component={Alumno_Inicio}/>
                    <Route path="nueva_incidencia" component={Alumno_NuevaIncidencia}/>
                    <Route path="mis_incidencias" component={Alumno_MisIncidencias}/>
                </Route>

                <Route path="administrador" component={AppAdministrador}>
                    <Route path="inicio" component={Administrador_Inicio}/>
                    <Route path="nueva_incidencia" component={Administrador_NuevaIncidencia}/>
                    <Route path="incidencias_recibidas" component={Administrador_IncidenciasRecibidas}/>
                    <Route path="incidencias_recibidas/nuevo_informe" component={Administrador_NuevoInforme}/>
                    <Route path="informes" component={Administrador_Informes}/>
                    <Route path="informes/nueva_respuesta_informe" component={Administrador_NuevaRespuestaInforme}/>
                </Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer your questions:

For the first question:

Yes, limiting access to routes is possible using this technology. There are several ways to do it, the simplest way to do it is to check for identity of the user in the `componentWillMount()` function. It may look something like this, depending on how you identify your user as an Administrador or an Alumno:

```
import React from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class YourComponent extends React.Component{

  componentWillMount(){
    //If user is an Alumno, throw them to '/some/path'
    if(this.state.isAlumno)
      browserHistory.push('/some/path');
  }

  render(){
    return <YourJsx />;
  }
}

export default YourComponent;
```

This way you don't need to change your routes.

You can also achieve the same functionality by having a higher order component (HOC) that returns the component you want to limit access to. If you want to go the HOC way, you first need to create a new component that may look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

//This function receives the Component that only some user should access
function RequireAdmin(ComposedComponent){

  class Authenticated extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount(){
      if(this.state.isAlumno)
        browserHistory.push('/some/path');
    }

    render(){
      return <ComposedComponent />;
    }
  }
  //Return the new Component that requires authorization
  return Authenticated;
}
```

Then, the route that you want to limit access to would look like this:

```
<Route path="administrador" component={RequireAdmin(AppAdministrador)}>
  ...
</Route>
```

Personally, I prefer the second way. It makes it clearer on the route which routes require what kind of authorization, and separates the components from the authorization.

---

To answer the second question:

It depends on how much of a hassle it would be. I'd certainly recommend learning the new API react-router v4, but I don't think it would be worth it to update an already built project, specially one with as many routes as yours.

Hope this helps! Buena suerte con React.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I loved that: 'Buena suerte con React' (I'm spanish) :D. But I do not understand something ... What I have to put it in `'/ some / path'` ?. And in `return () {} `?. The paths I put above are a .jsx called IndexRoutes.jsx (it's a component itself). I will collect the information if it is 'Alumno' or 'Administrador' from an AJAX query. Then I save this in State 'UserType' (this can be 'Student' or 'Admin'). Once this is done ... How do I restrict the routes that do not fit?

Comment: Agree! I'll keep that in mind, and I'll deploy the new version of React-Router on my next project. I'm sorry if it's rookie questions, but as I said in the question, I'm new to this technology. Again, thank you very much for the help offered.

Comment: Instead of `'some/path'` is maybe the homepage, or where ever you want to redirect when someone wants to access a route they should not. For example, redirect to `'alumno/inicio` if an Alumno tries to access an Administrador route. The first return should jsut be whatever you already had in the components, that does not change. In the second example, you should have in the return statement the component that you received as an argument to the function `RequireAdmin()` does that help?

Comment: Hey, we were all rookies haha. No need to apologize.

Comment: Thanks again! This afternoon / evening, when I get back to my development environment, I try it and tell you!.

Comment: Hi again! I have another question, If I have on my NavBar one state: isAdmin (NavBar is other component); how could I read this state from the other component (HOC)?. This way I would avoid performing an AJAX every route change, besides that in my NavBar component I already have that saved data. And another question.. In your example, where is stored `this.state.isAdmin`? Thank you!

Comment: So I took some liberties with where `this.state.isAdmin` is coming from, in my example it is not really coming from anywhere. What you could do is having the AJAX call in a container Component (Say, App) and App would send down `isAdmin` as props like so: `<NavBar isAdmin={this.state.isAdmin} />` or, in the HOC, as a function argument: `RequireAdmin(AppAdministrador, this.state.isAdmin`. That way you have is as an argument and can pass it to the component when rendered.

Comment: Ok! So.. in my example, container component will be '/' -App- isn't it?. There I may do the AJAX. Then I receive the state and pass it into NavBar like: `<NavBar isAdmin={this.state.isAdmin} />` but, the HOC is defined on other component, I was not very clear how to pass it to him. Thank you, sorry to be so heavy.

Comment: I create the component RequireAdmin, I pass it into Routes as you tell me, and it is entering correctly but... Only loads App('/') Regardless of the route in which I find myself. What could this be? Thank you. SOLVED: Only add RequireAdmin on the last child routes (not allowed in '/' or 'alumno' or '/administrador'. Only '/alumno/incio', etc.

Comment: Ok I get it!!! On my IndexRoutes did the AJAX and pass it in all routes like: `<Route path="inicio" component={RequireUser(Alumno_Inicio, this.state.isAdmin, this.state.isAlumno, this.state.isProf)}/>` is as you say? Thank you for all your help!